# How to get the number of the first row of a range in OpenOffice Calc (BASIC)

Tags: vba, openoffice-calc

So I have been converting a VBA code to OpenOffice BASIC and a simple task as getting the number of the first row of the range has been consuming hours of research.

in VBA:

Cells(3,2) or "mr" is a cell with an input of the kind "A5:G7", so first I splitted the string in a array with A5 and G7.

```
Rangesplit = Split(Cells(3, 2), ":") 
FirstRow = Range(Rangesplit(0)).Row
```

So far in OpenOfficeBasic:

```
Rangesplit(mr,":")
```

I have not been able so far to determine the row and I want to know which function allows me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following functions will probably help you:

```
Row_int = oCell.getCellAddress.Row
Col_int = oCell.getCell
```